# SQL Executing a Procedure on a different Server as a Different User

Tags: sql, execute, sql-server-2017

Scenario:

- Server `SQL1` has database `DB1`, procedure `Proc1` and user `USR1`
- Server `SQL2` has database `DB2`, procedure `Proc2` and user `USR2`

USR1 triggers `Proc1` to run. As last statement `Proc1` needs to execute `Proc2` on `SQL2.DB2` under authority of USR2.

I thought I could call from `SQL1.DB1.PROC1.USR1` a statement like:

```
EXECUTE AS USER SQL2.DB2.PROC2.USR2

GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::USR2 to USR1

EXEC @ProcName @Param1, @Result out
```

Am I correct or delusional?  Asking for your insights as me and SQL Server have some time got lost in translation

Comment: I'm presuming this is SQL Server you are referring to? Which version please

Comment: Yes, I apologize for omitting it.  It is Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: From your query it looks like you're executing it while connected to SQL1 and referencing SQL2 via linked server, is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Actually my user triggers PROC1 on SQL1, but PROC1 is calling an Assembly I added to the SQL Server on SQL2 to go set a value in one of the Wonderware Attributes in the Galaxy running on SQL2

Comment: You will need to have the user added to the SQL1 server and execute as the user on SQL1, then make sure that user has permissions to access the linked server